# Python 3.6 input crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a Celsius to Fahrenheit computer, but when I take the user's input, the program crashes.

I tried using raw_input, but i've got python 3.6.

```
print("Enter Celsius degrees to convert them into Fahrenheit degrees: ")
x = input()
y = x * 9 / 5 + 32
print(y)
input()
```

It should take the input, then automatically convert it into Fahrenheit, then print the Fahrenheit degrees.

Comment: And what actually happens? I mean, I know, but a good question details what is the actual outcome versus the expected one. your problem is that `input` returns a string. you want to do: `x = float(input())` to solve the problem

Comment: `input()` function returns `string`. You can cast it

Comment: Thank you.I didn't know the input always returns strings.You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function input() returns only string. Even if you type a number, the value in variable x will be string. 
For example, you type 20 as input. x == "20" will be true, but x == 20 will be false. For this reason you must convert your x into int or float to be able to use arithmetical operation using x . You can do it in two place.

1. When you are read data from input `x = float(input())`
2. Or when you use x to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit `y = float(x) * 9 / 5 + 32`